# blender api image.save() always creates solid black image

Tags: python, blender

i'm new to blender api
now i'm writing some code for create image and save into png file
the problem is that when save created image into png, it turns into solid black image
but i can't find any way to fix this problem on internet
please give me some hints

here is my code

```
    size = self.img_smap.size
    # blank image
    image = bpy.data.images.new("test.png", width=size[0], height=size[1], alpha=True)
    
    # solid white image
    pixels = [1.0] *(size[0]*size[1]*4)
    
    # set pixels
    image.pixels = pixels
   
    # save image
    settings = bpy.context.scene.split_map_settings
    image.filepath_raw = settings.test_save_path
    image.alpha_mode = 'STRAIGHT'
    image.file_format = 'PNG'
    image.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case  image.alpha_mode = 'STRAIGHT' was the problem
after remove that line, problem fixed
but i can't understand what is the difference
because 'STRAIGHT' is default value of image.alpha_mode